# Architecturing the router from design

Tags: ember.js

I am struggling to document the router for my design of a shop. The shop consists mainly of a article/product slider. See the image below:
[image: explanation of question]

**As you see:**

- on top an article navigation slider
- in the center the current selected article
- on the left the menu, which pages will be a popup over the current article
- when the user clicks the shoppingcart, go to checkout, open up a page, log in their account, or whatever they do, there will be always an active article.

**The router**

So I thought - and correct me if I am wrong - to the design my router as follows:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('articles', function() { // to fill the articles slider above
        this.resource('article', function(path: ':article_id') { // to show the current selected article in the slider

            // large popups - covers the current article almost 
            // completely with a little transparancy
            this.resource('page', function(path: ':page_id')); // shows a page from the menu
            this.resource('checkout', function(path: ':step_id')); // the checkout with multiple steps

            // small popups at the bottom of the page
            this.route('info'); // shows the additional product info popup
            this.route('shipping'); // shows the shipping info popup
        });

    });
});
```

Additional information: I use [Ember App Kit](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/) for developing and the slider will be [Flexslider 2](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) mainly because they have touch support.

It looks like a valid router, however the question is whether it is the Ember way.

Comment: pop-ups don't need routes. They need not to be maintained in the browsers url

Comment: Hi selva-G, thanks for your comment. However I want that if a user share a Page for example, that the link is correct . ie: `#/articles/article/1/page/2` which opens the page when a user put in that link directly.